# Braces around both sides of cases (with text)

Tags: braces, cases

How can I add curly braces around both sides of a cases environment which contains text?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\hat{C}(\hat{S},1) = \frac{1}{E} C(S,T) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } S<E,\\[1ex]
\frac{S}{2E} &\text{ if } S=E,\\[1ex]
\frac{S}{E} &\text{ if } S>E.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here, I replace the `cases` environment with a `\left\{\!\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\right\}`.  The `\!` seems necessary to overcome a small space introduced, I think by the leading `&`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\hat{C}(\hat{S},1) = \frac{1}{E} C(S,T) =
\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&0 &\text{ if } S<E,\\[1ex]
&\frac{S}{2E} &\text{ if } S=E,\\[1ex]
&\frac{S}{E} &\text{ if } S>E.
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted to preserve the `\textstyle` of the `cases` environment,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\hat{C}(\hat{S},1) = \frac{1}{E} C(S,T) =
\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&0 &\text{ if } S<E,\\[1ex]
&\textstyle\frac{S}{2E} &\text{ if } S=E,\\[1ex]
&\textstyle\frac{S}{E} &\text{ if } S>E.
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you use that if you want the `equation*` environment to allow alignment as well? 
Edit: I found. We can just use `\begin{aligned}` directly after `\begin{equation*}`.

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara  That is correct:  `equation*` plus `aligned`.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use the `(d)rcases` environment from `mathtools`.

Also, I think it's better to use `\widehat` with capital letters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \widehat{C}(\widehat{S},1) = \frac{1}{E} C(S,T) =
  \begin{rcases}
    \begin{dcases}
      0 & \text{ if } S<E, \\
      \frac{S}{2E} & \text{ if } S=E, \\
      \frac{S}{E} & \text{ if } S>E.
    \end{dcases}
  \end{rcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this does not always result in the left and right braces having the same height.

Comment: @jmd_dk: I never met the case. This isn't statistically significant, though…

Comment: @Bernard Very helpful, thank you. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the `\newcases` feature in `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcases{lrdcases}
  {\quad}
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
  {\lbrace}
  {\rbrace}
\newcases{lrdcases*}
  {\quad}
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
  {{##}\hfil}
  {\lbrace}
  {\rbrace}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\hat{C}(\hat{S},1) = \frac{1}{E} C(S,T) =
\begin{lrdcases}
0            &\text{if $S<E$,}\\[1ex]
\frac{S}{2E} &\text{if $S=E$,}\\[1ex]
\frac{S}{E}  &\text{if $S>E$.}
\end{lrdcases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\hat{C}(\hat{S},1) = \frac{1}{E} C(S,T) =
\begin{lrdcases*}
0            & if $S<E$,\\[1ex]
\frac{S}{2E} & if $S=E$,\\[1ex]
\frac{S}{E}  & if $S>E$.
\end{lrdcases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

According to the conventions of `mathtools`, the `*`-variant has the second column typeset in text mode.

[image]

However, I'd use the left brace only.