# How to properly use \collect@body within align environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

The following code (an example of using `\collect@body` as a test case for this specific question) modified `bmatrix` to *not* add the surrounding `[` and `]`. This seems to work fine, but requires that I insert an extra brace group when I attempt to use this within the `align` environment.

[image]

Without the extra brace group I get:

> Argument of \bmatrix has an extra }.

#### Question:

How do I modify this so that I do not need to have an extra brace group added when I attempt to use the `bmatrix` environment?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@MatrixWithoutBracs}[1]{%  
    \begin{matrix}%
        #1%  content
    \end{matrix}
}
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}{%
    \collect@body\@MatrixWithoutBracs%
}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
In \verb|equation| things work
\begin{equation*}
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and in \verb|align| had to use an extra brace group:
\begin{align*}
   A &= {\begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not just in the `align' environment; the  same happens in all amstex environments.  Strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the `&` tokens in the subsidiary environment, that should be protected from the outer environment. One of Knuth's dirty tricks that's often used in LaTeX is available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@MatrixWithoutBracs}[1]{%  
    \begin{matrix}
        #1%  content
    \end{matrix}%
}
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
   {{\ifnum0=`}\fi\collect@body\@MatrixWithoutBracs}
   {\ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
In \verb|equation| things work
\begin{equation*}
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and in \verb|align| had to use an extra brace group:
\begin{align*}
   A &= \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]