# Xparse k argument to parse options at end of environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, xparse, optional-arguments

I am trying to combine the solutions from

- [How to properly use \collect@body within align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319011/how-to-properly-use-collectbody-within-align-environment)
- [Xparse t argument type (underscore with optional parameter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319304/xparse-t-argument-type-underscore-with-optional-parameter)

to parse optional parameters following the *end* of an environment. There are only three possible cases with these options:

1. A subscript: `_{subscript}`
2. A superscript: `^{superscript}`
3. *Both* subscript and superscript: `_{subscript}^{superscript}`

The case of `^{subscript}_{superscript}` is *not* required.

I would have thought that adding the optional parameters to the `\@MatrixWithParen` helper macro would have sufficed, but it seems that the options don't get to that macro.

#### Attempted Solutions:

1. Use `\collect@body` to invoke `\@MatrixWithParen` which looks for optional parameters. Based on what egreg comments, this is not the way to go. The MWE yields what is on the left, and the desired result is on the right:

   [image]
   [image]
2. Store the content from `\collect@body` in a macro and use `\AfterEndEnvironment` to invoke a macro to parse the optional parameters.  This also seems that the optional parameters are not available to the macro specified to be executed by `\AfterEndEnvironment`.  Similarly `\aftergroup` and `\AtEndEnvironment` also did not work:

   [image]

   This non-solution has additional issues if there is more than one `bmatrix`  environemnt, but I think that could be solved with additional programming. Trying to keep this question focused on parsing optional parameters following an `end{environment}`.
3. Another thought I had was to modify `\collect@body` so that invokes a macro that allows for two optional parameters, but that is beyond my understanding.

### Notes:

- This question is *not* how to get a matrix with `()` instead of `[]` (which `pmatrix` can easily do), as this is just a MWE designed to illustrate my actual use case with minimal additional code.  That is, as per my other question, I need `#1` to be parameter to `\@MatrixWithParen` and not simply a subscript added outside of the macro (i.e., `\@MatrixWithParen` must be the one that invokes the actual subscript and superscript).

### Related Question:

- [Extending xparse for new arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245419/extending-xparse-for-new-arguments)

### General Question:

- How to parse optional parameters following a specfic `\end{environment}`?

---

### 1. Optional parameters parsed by macro invoked by `\collect@body`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\@MatrixWithParen}{m k_ k^}{%
    \left(
        \begin{matrix}%
            #1%  content
        \end{matrix}
    \right)
    %% These seem to have no effect
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{^{\textcolor{blue}{#3}}}%
}%

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrix}{}{%
   {\ifnum0=`}\fi\collect@body\@MatrixWithParen%
}{%
   \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   A &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Both subscript and superscript
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{2 \times 2}^{-1}
   \\
   B &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Only superscript
             1 & -1 \\
            -1 &  1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}^{2}
   \\
   C &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Only subscript
             a & b \\
             b & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

### 2: Attempt to use `\AfterEndEnvironment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@MatrixContents}{}%
\newcommand*{\@PostBMatrix}{\@PostBMatrixAux}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\@PostBMatrixAux}{k_k^}{%
    \@MatrixContents
    \IfValueT{#1}{_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{^{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@MatrixWithParen}{m}{%
    \gdef\@MatrixContents{%
        \left(
            \begin{matrix}
                #1%  content
            \end{matrix}
        \right)
    }%
    %\aftergroup{\@PostBMatrix}%
    %\AtEndEnvironment{bmatrix}{\@PostBMatrix}%   Not sure why this has slightly
    \AfterEndEnvironment{bmatrix}{\@PostBMatrix}% different spacing than this.
}%

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrix}{}{%
   {\ifnum0=`}\fi\collect@body\@MatrixWithParen%
}{%
   \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{2 \times 2}^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `xparse` you can use the argument specifiers in the end part of `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, but not define arguments for `\end{<name>}`; the arguments can only be given to `\begin{<name>}`

Comment: You seem to have unclear what `\collect@body` does; it should be followed by a macro with a *single* parameter, which is passed the body of the environment.

Comment: @egreg: My thought was that it would process the single parameter of `\collect@body` and then continue on in case there were additional parameters at the end of the environment. But, guess it does not work that way. So, what is the best way to be able to parse the parameters following a specific environment?

Comment: Use a macro after `\end{bmatrix}`. Or place the arguments after `\begin{bmatrix}`.

Comment: The LaTeX model is quite clear here: arguments are given to `\begin{foo}` only. Why not just use an optional argument to a custom environment?

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, I agree that the LaTeX model is clear, but the usual use with `bmatrix` is to put these _after_ the `\end{bmatrix}` environment, not after `\begin{bmatrix}`.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with `\AfterEndEnvironment` is that there's an extra `\if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi` bit of code after it. So the arguments `k_k^` never reach their intended sub- and super-scripts. You can move around this with an extra argument `u{\fi}` (or, if you want to be more cautious, may be `u{\if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}`, so it gives an error if that code is not present, I will use `u{\fi}` for simplicity).

Full code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrix}{}
 {{\ifnum0=`}\fi\collect@body\savematrix}
 {\ifnum0=`{\fi}}

\newcommand\matrixbody{}
\NewDocumentCommand\savematrix{m}{\gdef\matrixbody{#1}}

\AfterEndEnvironment{bmatrix}{\printmatrix}
\NewDocumentCommand\printmatrix{u{\fi} k_ k^}
 {\left(\begin{matrix}%
    \matrixbody
  \end{matrix}\right)%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{\textcolor{red}{\!#2}}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{\textcolor{blue}{\!#3}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Both subscript and superscript
          a_{11} & a_{12} \\
          a_{21} & a_{22} \\
      \end{bmatrix}_{2 \times 2}^{-1}
  \\
  B &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Only superscript
           1 & -1 \\
          -1 &  1 \\
      \end{bmatrix}^{2}
  \\
  C &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Only subscript
           a & b \\
           b & d \\
      \end{bmatrix}_{2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As a general suggestion, if you are not into looking at the definition or at the source (which might be a bit tedious, if you don't know where to look) you can define an auxiliar macro that would print into the document “what's there” and will let you easily check what might be wrong. For instance, if you define

```
\def\qq#1\qq{#1\par\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

the macro will grab everything until `\qq`, will put it back (so the code compiles) and will write all the code that it saw in `\tt` font in a new paragraph (remember to put the delimiting `\qq` —or whatever name you choose— outside math mode). Here are a few examples.

Imagine you used `\AtEndEnvironment` and it didn't work, a fast way to check why it doesn't work is

```
\AtEndEnvironment{bmatrix}{\qq}
$\begin{bmatrix} a \end{bmatrix}$ \qq
```

which will show “what's there” right away

[image]

It's fast and direct, you just now exactly what's going on there. Now if you use `\AfterEndEnvironment`

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{bmatrix}{\qq}
$\begin{bmatrix} a \end{bmatrix}$ \qq
```

[image]

Which is what I have done, hence we need to grab those four tokens and I decided to go with `u{\fi}` to grab *until* `\fi`.

It's not granted that it would work, but many times it will give you a fast overview of what's happening. You can just try it in case something goes wrong, it will take a second and it might solve your problem.

Comment: I know you know this, but really is an abuse of `xparse`: it's for defining document commands with LaTeX2e-like syntax, not arbitrary argument parsing. (Comment just to flag this up for any passing readers.)

Comment: Yes, I know it's a hack. But it's true that one might want to parse the sub/super-scripts after a matrix; the use of `xparse` here is only to save work, one could just program it manually with `\@ifnextchar`, etc.

Comment: Looks good. Will try it out in my actual use case tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterGrill If you are lazy to look at the code, there's always a trick you can use to check what's *there*. You define `\def\qq#1\qq{#1\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}` for instance, and then do `\AfterEndEnvironment{bmatrix}{\qq} \begin{bmatrix} a \end{bmatrix} \qq` And that will print what's exactly “hidden” there. It's really helpful for a fast debug, and may easily solve some problems in many occasions.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler and safer than @Manuel’s (very clever, anyway) solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% \usepackage{etoolbox} isn't actually necessary
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\renewenvironment*{bmatrix}{%
    {\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \collect@body\processmatrix
}{%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \processmatrix { m } {%
    \begingroup
    \RenewDocumentCommand \end {mk_k^}{%
        \endgroup
        \end{##1}%
        \left(\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}\right)%
        \IfValueT{##2}{_{\textcolor{red} {\!##2}}}%
        \IfValueT{##3}{^{\textcolor{blue}{\!##3}}}%
    }%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Both subscript and superscript
          a_{11} & a_{12} \\
          a_{21} & a_{22} \\
      \end{bmatrix}_{2 \times 2}^{-1}
  \\
  B &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Only superscript
           1 & -1 \\
          -1 &  1 \\
      \end{bmatrix}^{2}
  \\
  C &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Only subscript
           a & b \\
           b & d \\
      \end{bmatrix}_{2}
  \\
  D &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Neither subscript nor superscript
           a & b \\
           b & d \\
      \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  E &= \begin{bmatrix}                  %% Example of nesting
           \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ -y & x \end{bmatrix}^{h}
               & \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}^{k} \\
           \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}_{h}
               & \begin{bmatrix} x & -y \\ y & x \end{bmatrix}_{k}\\
      \end{bmatrix}_{2 \times 2}^{-1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It seems to cope correctly with nesting, too.  This is abusing `xparse`, anyway.

---

## Addition

One of the comments asks me to “elaborate on why this is ‘safer’”.  Well, there is a general reason, and it is that this solution makes no particular assumption about the code contained in the `\end` macro, so it would continue to work even if the latter were to change; and this certainly qualifies as “being safer”, in the sense of “more robust”.

However, when I originally wrote that sentence I had a much more specific issue in mind, which—as I realized later—was based on a false premise; this issue was briefly discussed in a couple of comments to Manuel’s answer that I deleted when I became aware of my error (actually, after a grace period of 48 hours).  I’ll see if there is a means to undelete them, thereby leaving them visible for reference.

Heaven knows why, I had assumed that the `\AfterEndEnvironment` command injected (a macro that expanded to) the code indicated in its second argument after the group implied by the environment being patched, by means of `\aftergroup`, which is not at all the case.  (Few things are as treacherous as the assumptions you make semi-unconciously.)  My idea was that, if it had been so, the mechanism devised by Manuel would have been thwarted if the `\if@endpe` switch had been set to true, as it is done, for example, by all environments based on either `\list` or `\trivlist`.  “The solution—I said, more or less, in a comment—works well for the case presented in the question, but could prove inadequate in general, for example when applied to ‘list-making’ environments”.

Let us explain briefly the issue.  The `\if@endpe` switch is part of the little hack by means of which the paragraph indentation is suppressed if a paragraph follows immediately an `\end{environment}` declaration, with no intervening blank lines.  So, for instance, if you say

```
\begin{center}
    Text inside.
\end{center}
Text after.
```

then “Text after” is *not* indented, as it had been preceded by `\noindent`.  The code that implements the `\end` macro, that is

```
\def\end#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
```

looks at this switch and, if it is true, execute the `\@doendpe` macro, which takes care of setting and resetting the definition of `\par` and of `\everypar` in such a way that the desired effect is achieved.  (I will not supply further details here: look at the definition of the `\@endparenv` macro in `ltlists.dtx` if you are curious.)  Note, however, that it says `\expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe`, which means that the order of execution of the commands is as follows:

1. First, the `\if@endpe` conditional is evaluated; if it is false,
   the tokens up to and including the matching `\fi`, that in this case
   is the `\fi` that follows `\@doendpe`, are immediately gobbled;
   if it is true, only the `\if@endpe` token disappears
   from the input stream,
   and execution continues with this conditional remaining “pending”.
2. `\endgroup` is executed, and the tokens saved for insertion
   after the current group are delivered exactly at his point.

Thus we see that, if it were true that `\AfterEndEnvironment` used `\aftergroup` to accomplish its task, the `\printmatrix` macro used by Manuel would find the following tokens intervening before the two `k`-arguments:

- if `\if@endpe` is false,

  ```
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi
  ```

  with no pending conditional;
- if `\if@endpe` is true,

  ```
  \@doendpe\fi\if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces
  ```

  with the `\if@endpe` conditional still pending.

You can see that the second case might be problematic…

All this can be confirmed by means of some simple experiments, of course not using `\AfterEndEnvironment`, but rather `\aftergroup` to insert a macro similar to the `\qq` test macro, that Manuel suggest in the second part of his answer, “after” (in the sense specified above) a certain environment.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\def\qq#1\qq{ (%
    level:~\number\currentiflevel,
    type:~\number\currentiftype,
    branch:~\number\currentifbranch
    \space \detokenize{#1})#1%
}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment*{grabtest}{}{%
    \aftergroup\qq
    % \@endpetrue
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Text before.

\begin{grabtest}Text inside\end{grabtest}\qq

Text after.

\end{document}
```

Commenting or uncommenting the `\@endpetrue` command will exhibit, in the output, exactly the two outcomes described above.

The following source file shows what would happen if Manuel’s approach were used in conjunction with `\aftergroup`: this is precisely what I was thinking of when I qualified my solution as being “safer” than his.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand \qq {u{\if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi} k_ k^ } {%
    \unskip\space(%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{subscript:   $#2$}{no subscript},
    \IfValueTF{#3}{superscript: $#3$}{no superscript})%
}

\newenvironment*{genericthing}{}{%
    \aftergroup\qq
    \@endpetrue
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Text before.

\begin{genericthing}Text inside\end{genericthing}_{a\times b}^{\pi}

Text after.

\end{document}
```

The example compiles, but you get a warning about an incomplete conditional:

```
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 31 was incomplete)
```

In this case, this does not hurt, but in general it *could* be a problem!

One final remark: Manuel’s solution works correctly with nesting, notwithstanding the use of `\global` definitions, because the order in which these definitions are executed happens to be (but *not* by chance!) the “right” one.

Comment: Remember that you are not inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` so you may want to add a few `%`.

Comment: @Manuel: Are you sure?  The examples in the `xparse` manual use spaces freely…

Comment: Yes, but those spaces don't matter if you are inside `\ExplSyntaxOn .. \ExplSyntaxOff`. In this case the definition of the command `\processmatrix` is done outside, so you need to add `%` as usual.

Comment: @Manuel: It seems you are right, I admit I didn’t know.  Thank you very much, I’ll update!

Comment: Very clever, in any case ;)

Comment: This seems to work great. Can you elaborate on why this is "safer"?  Manuel's version seems to handle the nested case as well.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Please see edit.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Mmmhh… Thanks, but I feel like having stolen a bounty that was originally meant for Manuel.  Have you got anything to object if I share it with him?

Comment: I had stated that I will offer a bounty _beofre_ Manuel's answer. Your answer seemd simpler, so I choose that. But, anywhow, I will remedy the situation.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Wow, you are very prodigal with your reputation points!